# Adding favicon in website

Tags: html, css, favicon

Is there anyway to add `favicon [GIF & ICO]` through CSS or I need to add the tag in every HTML pages ?

Comment: every HTML page: unstructured application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The favicon can not be defined in CSS. If you want reliable behaviour, you should use the HTML tags.

Browsers will usually automatically look at `/favicon.ico` if an icon isn't defined in HTML. Putting an `.ico` file here will work in all browsers, but this won't work for other file types.

Comment: anything possible with `.htaccess` ?

Comment: "'must use HTML' means 'must use HTML'"

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about having the Icon in CSS but if you put the icon in the root folder of your site browsers will show the icon correctly. (As A ICO Format)

This has good information here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: Personally I would stick to ICO format because gif is not supported in Internet Explorer according to this article I listed in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

An html tag is a reliable way to achieve this effect. Of note, the current auto-generated tags from favicon.io have broken end tags, so you will need to fill them in. Additionally, I recommend adding an additional line to include the href for the favicon.ico file that they auto generate for you as well.

[snip of favicon website as of 30JAN24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyMYX.png)